# React Router not rendering component at path, returns blank page with correct pathing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

React-Router appears to be working in my app except for the fact that I am getting a blank page instead of my component, even though it is directed to the proper path.

I'm scanning the documentation but I can't resolve the issue on my own after looking it over and searching Google/this site.

I had tried...

- Making it so that the router.js file just contained the routes only to get the same results. Specifying exact path as well when doing so.
- Reinstalling react-router-dom into the component in case there was an error when it downloaded.
- Removing the provider in case that was the issue
- Placing the code in the router file directly in the App.js file between the provider component tags

These are the files involved.

Router.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import LandingPage from '../scenes/LandingPage';
import CityPage from '../scenes/CityPage';

const Router = () => {
    return ( 
        <Switch>
            <Redirect from='/' to='/landing' />
            <Route path='/landing' component={LandingPage} />
            <Route path='/citypage' component={CityPage} />
        </Switch>
     );
}

export default Router;
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Router from "./services/Router";
import ChosenCityContextProvider from "./services/context/ChosenCityContext";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <ChosenCityContextProvider>
        <Router />
      </ChosenCityContextProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

No error messages accompany the rendering of the site. Aside from the blank page, everything else appears to be working. In the React Dev tools, it states that the Router.Consumer has an object which is revealed to empty when expanded.

What is wrong with my code?

https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-maxwell-rch1k?fontsize=14

Above is sandbox of code. I have the same issue here

Comment: Can you include the jsfidle link to your question. It's easy to debug your code :)

Comment: I will make up a sandbox real quick

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-maxwell-rch1k?fontsize=14

Comment: @Jargal sorry I should have tagged you

Comment: I'm not certain why this works, but if you add `exact` your page renders in the sandbox.

Comment: @DLowther thats strange. When i tried that earlier it didn't work. You added exact to the first Route?

Comment: @DLowther please write an answer so I can give you points for this. I put your solution in an answer to my question, but I want to accept your answer as I did not think of this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not certain why exactly this fixes the issue, but I've run into this on a work project so knew it worked.

If you add `exact` into the redirect element it forces the correct behavior.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import LandingPage from '../scenes/LandingPage';
import CityPage from '../scenes/CityPage';

const Router = () => {
    return ( 
        <Switch>
            <Redirect exact from='/' to='/landing' />
            <Route path='/landing' component={LandingPage} />
            <Route path='/citypage' component={CityPage} />
        </Switch>
     );
}

export default Router;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @DLowther. I am not sure either given that the pathing matches exactly, but I am grateful to have a solution to my issue. I have read that "from" is treated as "path" in the documentation. So I understand that, but not why sharing the name was not enough to get it to work properly

Comment: Here is great explanation about 'exact'. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool. But I am curious about how "exact" is working @A-Bro 's example. There is no router with same name. If someone know about this please explain us :)

Comment: @Jargal thank you for the helpful link Jargal. The link goes to the page so the fact that the component just doesn’t show up is puzzling indeed

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked. I'm not sure why before it didn't. If anyone has an explanation please let me know because I am trying to learn what I did wrong initially.

```
            <Route render={() => <Redirect from='/' to='/landing' />} />
```

I added the above, so my router file looked like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import LandingPage from '../scenes/LandingPage';
import CityPage from '../scenes/CityPage';

const Router = () => {
    return ( 
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/landing' component={LandingPage} />
            <Route path='/citypage' component={CityPage} />
            <Route render={() => <Redirect from='/' to='/landing' />} />
        </Switch>
     );
}

export default Router;
```

@DLowther has also showed me another solution

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Page from "./Page";
import Home from "./Home";

const Router = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Redirect exact from="/" to="/home" />
      <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/page" component={Page} />
    </Switch>
  );
};

export default Router;
```

I would like to credit this individual for answering my question

Comment: the render method is also pretty useful in a lot of cases. We use it to detect private routes (you can extract a wrapper component ), and conditionally render either a login screen or the requested route.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information @DLowther! I am glad to know of the different use cases for this particular format.